# C# & VSAEngine - Calculating a string expression with a exponent?

Tags: c#, exponent, jscript.net, managed-jscript

i've a prob here, so i need a help:)

When i'm calculating expression like this "(10.5 + 3.5 / 2) * 2" with jscript vsa engine, it's ok, but now i 've a question...
if in the string like above, i want to calculate also an exponent (10.5 + 3.5 / 2) * 2 + exp(2), what is the best way to do it?

PS: Math.Exp(); -- is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proper way to code this is to make your calculations in integer and then Convert.ToString() it

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jscript.net you can define `exp` function first and calculate expression after that. example was discussed for instance [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67734/execute-javascript-from-within-a-c-sharp-assembly)